# Symfony2, GregWar image bundle crashes due to picture size

Tags: image, symfony, gd

I am using GregWar image bundle to handle images on my website:

https://github.com/Gregwar/Image/

It works quite good until an error appeared and destroyed the application for several hours until I found the problem and removed the image so it's not blocking the load of the app.

The user uploaded a transparent PNG 8000x7000px big (yes the description of the image is ironic)

[image]

The application dies when trying to resize this picture and returns only white page, 503 error.

On my local machine I am able to resize it and no error occurs. The server is very powerful Centos 7 with enough resources.

**Whats the best solution for this case?**

1. Should I increase a memory limit or something like that? (currently 400MB)
2. Prevent uploading those kind of images?

Answer (score 1):

The bundle you're mentioning seems to use GD PHP extension to adapt pictures. This extensions seems not to handle well big pictures in terms of memory.
You could either change the bundle you're using for another one (like Imagick library but you might encounter same kind of issue).

You could also as you said increase the PHP limit on your server, but this solution has its limit, depending on the server memory you have.
I would recommend to put a limitation in the upload file size (if you are uploading the pictures) and the dimensions of your pictures.

You could also use some client-side solutions to resize pictures before upload.

Comment: Hmm seems like I am going to check the dimensions of the pictures. But that's not the best solution. I have plenty of resources. Which parameter should I increase to make it work properly? Because it cannot be a memory limit problem. I think it's something else. Like a process timeout or something like that. And the most weird part is that I tried to change the memory limit on my local to just 128MB and it was still resized without problems.

Comment: Which options did you change for the memory limit? memory_limit? I am not sure if this kind of changes can be effective immediately. Maybe you can check with a phpinfo() if the changes really worked. If you have also access to the server, you might also have some logs to see what causes the issue(depending on your server provider)